# Spell Check not working in Word 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

Spell check and grammar check not working in Word 2007 Pro.

Its definately enabled, the dictionary is correct, clicking on "check spelling" button says the spell check is complete, when it is not.

MS Proofing tools are installed correctly. All settings are correct.

Have re-installed Office and still nothing

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is it doing this with any/all docments, or just some?

Comment: all documents.J

Comment: Did it ever work? If you type soemthing like "qwert qwert" does it underline the second word as 'repeated'?

Answer (score 0):

There are several posted solutions to this issue online now:

1. [Slipstick](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/spell-check-is-not-working/) recommends either deleting or creating the registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\ProofingTools\1.0\Override\en-US`, which *may* fix it.
2. Ensure that the spellchecking add-in is enabled (Office orb, word options, add-ins, change list item to 'disabled' from 'COM add-ins', click "Go" then "enable" next to spell-check if it is listed there.
3. Another option I found was to disable or reduce the sensitivity of the touchpad on certain Dell laptops.

None of these worked for me. Being that the devices I was working with were not laptops, nor Dell, and it had worked prior to the 1703 upgrade, I suspect the Windows 10 build 1703 may be at fault.

There's still a workaround, however:

In the spellcheck window that shows when you press F7 or the "Spelling & Grammar" button, click the "Undo edit" button in the top-right corner after the window opens and this will allow you to proceed to spellcheck the document. It's one extra click each time you need to run spellcheck, but at least it works. Confirmed to work on both devices I observed the problem on, in Word; Excel; and Outlook. Good luck.